# C# SSH Client Output Encoding Issue

Tags: c#, ssh, encoding, utf-8

I have the following issue with the C# SshClient class:
When getting the output from a command that has been sent to a remote machine, special characters like "öäü" and so on get encoded in a weird way. I already checked the encoding on the remote device, it's UTF-8 (de_De) for sure. I also made sure to set the encoding of the ConnectionInfo that is being used by the SshClient to UTF-8. Yet the output of the command looks like this:
[image: Output]

I create the instance of the SshClient like following:

```cs
var connectionInfo = new ConnectionInfo(host
                                        username
                                        new PasswordAuthenticationMethod(username, password));

connectionInfo.Encoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;

var sshClient = new SshClient(connectionInfo);
```

I even tried to manually encode the string to utf-8 but that also didn't help.
Thanks for answers.

Comment: It looks like you're viewing the output in a terminal window? What character set is the terminal window using?

Comment: @Kenster I'm actually not, it's just a "pre" HTML element that has been styled to look like a terminal window. The output I get and put inside that pre element is directly from our API that sends the command to the remote machine.

Comment: What is meta charset of the web page? Should be `<meta charset="utf-8">`

Comment: @aepot it is utf-8, the backend already sends the output like that

Comment: What kind of OS on other side of SSH? What's terminal encoding there? `connectionInfo.Encoding` tells SSH client what emcoding is currently in SSH but it doesn't change the encoding of the connection itself. SSH server is not aware of that operation. Myaybe you need setup the TTY to transfer in UTF-8.

Comment: @aepot I just checked, the OS is Ubuntu Server 18.04 and the encoding there is de_CH-UTF-8